# why string multiplied by and integer and variable multiplied by integer is not same?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose on the following example:

```
a='a'
```

while multiplying by an integer both a*2 and 'a' *2 yields same result

```
>>a*2
'aa'
>>'a' *2 
'aa'
```

however this does not hold same for comparing:

```
>>a*2 is 'aa'
False
>>'a' * 2 is 'aa'
True
>> a*2 is 'a' *2
False
```